# How to check if control draws in its bounds?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a rather complex control which sometimes draws outside its bounds. I know I can check (visually) if it exceeds its bounds by adding ClipToBounds=True and checking if the drawing is clipped.

My question is: how can I check the opposite, i.e. if the control does fill all of its bounds? I tried setting Background, but it doesn't work.